# React Native showing cryptic stack trace instead of file names

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, debugging

The stack trace for my react native app has had the functions and component names and files replaced with what looks like compiled names instead of their given names.

Additionally, the file names are replaced with something starting with `AppEntry.bundle` followed by a bunch of parameters. How do I revert back to proper stack traces?

[image: Stack trace is indecipherable]

[image: Red screen shows compiled function names]

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and redownloading the repo seemed to work. Not sure what happened, but this solved my issue completely.